# Error Running App "The SplashScreen Activity is not Declared in Manifest"

Tags: java, android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.aliraza.Trackwiz">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/trackwizlogoupdated"
        android:label="TrackWiz"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        tools:replace="android:label"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />

        <activity android:name=".SignUpActivity" />

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />

        <activity android:name=".Welcomescreen" />

        <activity android:name=".YoutubeDownloader.YoutubeDownloaderInterface" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I am facing this problem so I change the Default Activity to Specified Activity. but it didn't show any positive sign. After this, it showing that "Activity" is not specified in Android Manifest folder

Comment: Try changing `android:name=".SplashScreen"` to `android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"` and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new `<activity>` tag for it. Don't replace a current one.

Change

```
<activity android:name=".SplashScreen" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Back to whatever it was before.

Then register your SplashScreen Activity by adding this line to your Manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".SplashScreen" />
```

Comment: You should really share the error then, along with the structure of your classes (paste the stacktrace, take a screenshot of your sidebar with the java folder and sub-folders expanded)

Comment: _And_ the stacktrace, _as text_? @AliRaza

Comment: no! how can I post the stacktrace as text? I don't know how to add the screenshot in comments basically I am new in this StackOverflow

Comment: Just copy it and paste it into your question. Highlight it in your question and press Ctrl+K to format it. Don't add things in the comments. Edit your question.